# How can I mark a message Forwarded in the Client Synchronize to the server?

Tags: c#, mailkit

when I How  Forward a mail in the Client ,the mail status will be Forwarded,  but   the server never has a forwarding flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP does not have a concept of "Forwarded", so IMAP does not have a Forwarded flag. It only has an `\Answered` flag which most clients use to denote that the message has been replied to.

If your server supports custom flags, your other IMAP client(s) may be using a custom flag for this (such as "$Forwarded"). MailKit allows you to set custom flags as well:

```
var customFlags = new HashSet<string> ();
customFlags.Add ("$Forwarded");

folder.AddFlags (uids, MessageFlags.None, customFlags, true);
```